# how to show Loading image on binding dropdownlist data with fancy tree

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, fancytree

On dropdownlist value change, im calling ajzx action to get the DB values and building DB values as Html (in controller) and onSuccess of Ajax the Html is appended to the an div. Till this the process is speed and i can get the data in few seconds. the appended Div element is converted to fancytree (plugin) which takes long time to load, so the requirement is to show the 'Loading...' icon still the binding completes. I googled a lot and tired many sort but nothing working, the image is not loading during converting the div to fancy Tree. Shown below the code which i tired.

CSS:

```
#dvLoading {
   background:#000 url(images/animated-overlay.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

in View :

```
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

in JS

```
drawOrganiTree: function (result) {
    "use strict";
    var ns = SocietaEStruttureHome.index;
    var res = "<div id='divOrgTree' >" + result + "</div>";
    $("#divOrgStructure").append(res); //append the HTML data 

    //$(window).load(function () { $("#dvLoading").fadeOut(20000); });
    $("#dvLoading").show(); // Here to show the Loading image

    $("#divOrgTree").fancytree();

    $("#dvLoading").show(); //Here to hide the Loading image
    //Expand all the node of the tree on load
    $("#divOrgTree").fancytree("getRootNode").visit(function (node) {
        //node.setExpanded(true);
    });

    $("#btnModify").show();
},
```

Am i doing anything wrong here. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div id="dvLoading" class="spinner-loading" style="display: none;">
   <img id="img-spinner" alt="Loading" src="http://www.vetsbye.com/eng/img/loader.gif">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.spinner-loading {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1234;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Div inside body tag(immediate after <body> begin)

Comment: Do one thing. Let the page load and then Inspect Element (F12) find the loading div and then change its inline css to display block and see if the loading div then shows up.

Comment: Yes, when i chaged the div to block, i can see the block in the mid of the page with some co-ordinates.